# Makefile ifeq always true

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile target:

```
target1:
    $(eval count_abc := $(shell grep -c "ABC" myFileA))
    $(eval count_def := $(shell grep -c "DEF" myFileB))
    echo $(count_abc)
    echo $(count_def)
ifeq ($(count_abc),$(count_def))
    echo "TRUE"
else
    echo "FALSE"
endif
```

But the output is always TRUE, e.g.:

```
echo 22
22
echo 21
21
echo TRUE
TRUE
```

What am I doing wrong here? What I want is INSIDE the target do 2 greps and compare their outputs and do something or something else based on the result. Please note that the greps must be done within the target since myFileA and myFileB get created on the target before and don't exist at the beginning when running make.

Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 0):

The rule file for "make" is declarative in nature - the makefile defines rules and targets, and then the make program evaluate the rules, and decide which action to take based on the target. As a result, execution is not always in the order the lines are entered into the file.

More specifically, the "ifeq" is evaluated at the rule definition stage, but the actions for building the target (`eval count_abc ...`) are executed when the target is built. As a result, when the ifeq is processed, both `count_abc` and `count_def` are still uninitialized, expanded to empty strings.

For the specific case you described - building a target that will compare the `grep -c` output from the two files, you can try something like below, effectively using shell variables (evaluated when target is evaluated), and not make variables (which are mostly declarative, evaluated when makefile is read)

```
target1:
    count_abc=$(grep -c "ABC" myFileA) ; \
    count_def=$(grep -c "DEF" myFileB) ; \
    echo $(count_abc) ; \
    echo $(count_def) ; \
    if [ "$count_abc" -eq "$count_def" ] ; then echo TRUE ; else echo FALSE ; fi
```

Disclaimer: I did not run the revised makefile, not having access to desktop at this time.

Comment: Thank you. I tried all possible type of combinations I could think of but couldn't get this working. It's either giving error messages or it's still not working as expected. I'm giving up now and will put these few lines in a script and just call the script at that stage. I would appreciate if you could give it a try when you're back at your desktop. Thanks again!

Comment: The error in this is that you have to escape all `$` that you want to send to the shell, which in this case is _all_ of them.  Also you have to use shell variable syntax, not make variable syntax, so no parenthesis.  So you need `count_abc=$$(grep ...) ; \ ... echo $$count_abc ; \ ... if [ "$$count_abc" -eq "$$count_def" ] ; then ...`

Comment: The way to write a correct recipe in a makefile is **first** write a command at your shell prompt that does what you want, then **second** copy that command into your makefile recipe and replace all `$` with `$$`.